# Histrorical Trend report on custom object - creating charts - missing Summary Format

Tags: reporting, charts, analytics

Summary format is missing in historical trend report.But as you know, to be able to create charts, i need summary or matrix format. Is it normal situation for Historical Trend reports?Do you guys any idea about it?Thank You.

[image: historical trending]

Comment: "Show: All projects"... Is this a custom object? Renamed Opportunity object? A regular report on that object or maybe on the field history tracking table? What happens if you'll use Matrix but populate only "row groups" or only "column groups" and run it?

Comment: Yeah it's custom object.It worked like how you said actually.I made it matrix and only used column group.